# Как можно реализовать самому простой SMTP client (System.Net.Mail)?

Tags: c#, smtp

При помощи каких средств можно реализовать самому SMTP client (System.Net.Mail), если я использую

```
  new SmtpClient();
  Port 
  Host                     
  EnableSsl 
  DeliveryMethod 
  UseDefaultCredentials                  
  Credentials
  Send(new MailMessage())
```

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,ebaa2d61cfed8051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете посмотреть мою реализацию здесь: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Network/Smtp/SmtpConnection.cs

Используется вот так:

```
var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("mail_acc@mail.ru", "Вася Петрович");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@gmail.com", "Антон"));
message.Body = "Привет";
message.Subject = "Прочитай";
message.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment
{
    ContentType = ContentType.Image.Png, // обязательно нужно указать ContentType
    Filename = "кирилица в имени файла.png",
    Content = File.ReadAllBytes("screenshot.png")
});

var smtp = new SmtpConnection();
// соединяемся
smtp.Connect("smtp.mail.ru", 587);

// extended hello команда, ее параметр ни на что не влияет
smtp.ExtendedHello("bla-bla");
// переходим в защищенное соединение
// параметр отвечает за адрес домена, по которому будет проверяется SSL-сертификат 
smtp.StartTls("mail.ru");

// снова отправляем extended hello, таковы требования протокола
smtp.ExtendedHello("bla-bla");
// авторизуемся
smtp.AuthPlain("mail_acc", "password");

message.Send(smtp);

// quit команда сообщает серверу о конце соединения
smtp.Quit();
```

Comment: Как правильно это все добавить в мой проект?

Comment: @Nikita Можете сбилдить целый проект в dll-ку. Или добавлять классы по одному, и смотреть, каких не хватает, и т.д.

Comment: А можно построчно пояснить,за что каждая строка отвечает?

Comment: @Nikita добавил

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: А вложения(картинки или .zip файлы ) можно с помощью вашего  smtp отправлять?

Comment: @Nikita нельзя, но я думаю там не очень сложно добавить

Comment: @Nikita я добавил возможность прикреплять файлы, если нужно, могу обновить пример использования

Comment: Да,обновите пожалуйста)

Comment: @Nikita обновил, MailMessage мой класс, а не .net-овский

Comment: хорошо,еще раз спасибо)